# pull/push from gitlab results in Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab, public-key

I'm using both git bash and VS code to connect to my gitlab repository. Everything was working fine until I created a new repo and tried to clone it locally via git bash. 
The error I received was:

```
git@gitlab.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I've tried changing the permissions of the ./ssh folder and the public key, adding an ssh to agent, none of those worked.

Executing `ssh -Tv <user name>@gitlab.com` shows the following output:

```
OpenSSH_8.2p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to gitlab.com [172.65.251.78] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /c/Users/user/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /c/Users/user/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.8
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.8 pat OpenSSH_7.0*,OpenSSH_7.1*,OpenSSH_7.2*,OpenSSH_7.3*,OpenSSH_7.4*,OpenSSH_7.5*,OpenSSH_7.6*,OpenSSH_7.7* compat 0x04000002
debug1: Authenticating to gitlab.com:22 as 'user'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:HbW3g8zUjNSksFbqTiUWPWg2Bq1x8xdGUrliXFzSnUw
debug1: Host 'gitlab.com' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /c/Users/user/.ssh/known_hosts:7
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: pubkey_prepare: ssh_get_authentication_socket: Bad file descriptor
debug1: Will attempt key: /c/Users/user
/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:rNZDTqdiVzM9+qjPlPV9wpd5Eg0t0tKKMonz+Q6+yGo
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /c/Users/user/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:rNZDTqdiVzM9+qjPlPV9wpd5Eg0t0tKKMonz+Q6+yGo
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
<user name>@gitlab.com: Permission denied (publickey).
```

Answer (score 0):

> I've tried changing the permissions of the ./ssh folder and the public key, adding an ssh to agent, none of those worked.

First, make sure you have [registered the content of `id_rsa.pub` to your GitLab SSH keys profile page](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ssh/#adding-an-ssh-key-to-your-gitlab-account).

If it still does not work, try and regenerate that key, without passphrase (fo testing, and ruling out any ssh-agent issue, which is used only for caching passphrase)

```
ssh-keygen -m PEM -t rsa -P ""
```

Make sure your [Git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases) is up-to-date (2.27).

Make sure to `set GIT_SSH=` (meaning to *unset* `GIT_SSH`, which should not refers to `putty.exe`).